# Spring JSF security login to prevent multiple users login

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a web application configured with spring security and JSF and https. 
The issue is after I login to the application, if I access the login page again in a new tab in same browser and try to login with a another user it authenticates and logs in the first user again to the second tab(i.e. when I provide second users credentials, which should not happen practically).

1) Rather than allowing the second browser tab with login page How can I check whether a user already loggedIn when login page URL is requested in the browser and redirect to the same protected page like in gmail. So it will be a single user login for a specific browser.

2) Or else How can I allow two users login in same browser with two tabs or so?

***Login Bean***

```
public class LoginBean implements Serializable{

    private String username;    
    private String password;
    private UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;

    public UserDetailsManager getUserDetailsManager() {
        return userDetailsManager;
    }
    public void setUserDetailsManager(UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager) {
        this.userDetailsManager = userDetailsManager;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String login()throws IOException, ServletException{

        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
                .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check?j_username="+username+"&j_password="+password);

                dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
                        (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        return null;

    }
}
```

***Spring-security.xml***

```
    <http auto-config="true">
        <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
        <form-login login-page="/faces/index.xhtml"
            default-target-url="/faces/xxxx/protectedPage.xhtml"
            always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/faces/index.xhtml?error=true" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/faces/xxxx/protectedPage.xhtml" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>

    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
    </port-mappings>

    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/faces/index.xhtml" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />

    <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession" invalid-session-url="/faces/index.xhtml" session-authentication-error-url="/faces/index.xhtml?errorMessage=The session is expired due to another user logging in with your user name and password.">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/sessionExpired.xhtml?errorMessage=The session is expired! Please reLogin" />
    </session-management> 

    </http>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:MyDS" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

***Faces-config.xml***

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>loginBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.xxxx.jsf.security.LoginBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
   <property-name>userDetailsManager</property-name>
   <value>#{userDetailsManager}</value>
  </managed-property>
 </managed-bean>
<application>
  <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
 </application>
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.ustocktrade.jsf.listener.LoginErrorPhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

***web.xml***

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
  <param-value>2</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
  <param-value>2</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/user-config.xml 
  /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>server</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
  <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources/log4j.properties</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
  <param-value>1000</param-value>
 </context-param>
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <error-page>
  <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
  <location>/sessionExpired.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/errors/404.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>403</error-code>
  <location>/errors/403.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/errors/500.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>
```

Comment: Are you handling your login.jsp from a Controller method?  If so, you could include the Principal on the method signature, and only display the login if the principal tests as `null`.  I think the reason you can't have two users logged in on the same browser has to do with sessions.

Comment: No Im not using a controller for this. Certainly its has something to do with sessions.@CodeChimp

Comment: Well, if you handle your login as a controller method, you should be able to use the process I mentioned.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to do it @CodeChimp

Comment: Create a controller (or use an existing one).  Make a handler method for `/login` or `/login.htm` or whatever.  Add `Principal` as one of the arguments to said handler method.  Configure the login URL for Spring Security to point to that URL for login.  Make sure that URL is open to everyone in your config.  In the handler method, check if the Prinicipal is null, if it is, return `login.jsp`, if it's not, return a redirect to somewhere else or a page saying the user is already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

In your login-form use your default target url as your home page link.So that it will redirect to the home page once it is authenticated and authorized .

```
<form-login login-page="/rest/admin/adminLogin" 
                        default-target-url="/rest/admin/adminHome"
                        login-processing-url="/rest/admin/login_process"
                        authentication-failure-url="/rest/admin/adminLogin?error" 
                        username-parameter="emailId"
                        password-parameter="password" 
                        always-use-default-target="true" />
```

Once you observe the above code there I used adminHome as my default target url after successful login.If it is not authenticated means it will redirect to again login page.But logging with two accounts in same browser is not possible only with spring security it only possible with spring session multi login feature with session persisting at some where (like persisting your session tokens in cookie,header or using spring-data(redis,nosql...)/RDBMS